# get(CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_AE_AVAILABLE_TARGET_FPS_RANGES) in CameraCharacteristics returns differently by OS version

Tags: android, android-camera2

Tested OS ver. & device : Android 5.0.2/6.0.1 both device are Galaxy Tab S2

When I attempt to access camera through Camera2 APIs to get fps ranges the device supporting, I get a weird result from get(CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_AE_AVAILABLE_TARGET_FPS_RANGES).

If I try this on Android 5.0.2, I get fps ranges like below,
[[15000, 15000], [24000, 24000], [15000, 30000], [30000, 30000]].

But if I try this code on the same device but different OS version(6.0.1), I get different result like below.
[[15, 15], [24, 24], [15, 30], [30, 30]]

Why are these results different? I think it was cause by different OS version.

For better understanding, I put some of my code here which was written referencing [this](https://developer.android.com/samples/Camera2Video/src/com.example.android.camera2video/Camera2VideoFragment.html).

```
CameraManager manager = (CameraManager)activity.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
...
String cameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[0];
CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
Range<Integer>[] fpsRanges = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_AE_AVAILABLE_TARGET_FPS_RANGES);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there was a bug on earlier Android versions where the values for available FPS ranges were incorrect on some devices; this was fixed in a later release, as you see on 6.0.1.

The values are supposed to be just frames per second; they were inadvertently 1000*frame rate.

This does mean you have to be careful interpreting this value on older OS releases, especially on LEGACY devices.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @EddyTavala . I reported this on [AOSP Issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=216003&sort=-opened&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened&start=200) but am not sure how they fix this as fast as I expected. Or even they may just leave this as it is. :(

Comment: One more question @EddyTalvala Is there any possibility that google developers revise this issue on older OS releases too? If not, should I not use this APIs  on legacy devices which is older OS version than Android 6.0?

Comment: There is no way to fix older OS releases, besides updating them to newer ones. That's more or less by definition.